# How to write virtually aligned superscript and subscript

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

I have this line:

```
\textbf{Adv}\textsuperscript{downgrade}\textsubscript{$Pi$, DP, X}
```

But I get this output:
[image]

And I want it like this:
[image]

Can you help me with simple solutions as much as possible plz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `\rlap` and some `\raisebox` because of ascenders and descenders in the us/superscript:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Adv}\textsubscript{\raisebox{-1pt}{\rlap{$\Pi$, DP, X}}}\textsuperscript{\raisebox{1pt}{downgrade}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Added:*

The code given above supposes the user knows which is shortest, of the superscript or the subscript text. The shortest has to to be enterd in the code first, the `\rlap`ped. The following code, based on `eqparbox` makes it automatic:

```
\textbf{Adv}\textsuperscript{\raisebox{1pt}{\rlap{\eqmakebox[subp][l]{downgrade}}}}\textsubscript{\raisebox{-1pt}{\eqmakebox[subp][l]{$\Pi$, DP, X}}}
```

Comment: This won't work if the subscript is wider than the superscript. Which is not a problem in the answer to the question this one is a duplicate of. And the “close as duplicate” vote was given several minutes before you answered.

Comment: @egreg: For the first point, I should have explained it's up to the user, in each case, which of the sub or superscript has to be ‘rlapped’. For the ‘close as duplicate’, I must say I didn't notice. Shall I withdraw my answer?

Comment: I think that you should at least fix it. If you agree it's a duplicate, vote.

Comment: @egreg: Well, the question is indeed a duplicate, but my solution (which is now automatic, hopefully) does not rely on mathmode…

Comment: `\textsuperscript` and `\textsubscript` *do* rely on math mode anyway.

Comment: @egreg: I didn't know that.

Comment: `\@textsuperscript:
macro:#1->{\m@th \ensuremath {^{\mbox {\fontsize \sf@size \z@ #1}}}}`

Comment: @egreg: I see (more or less…). Thanks for the information!